# "had I stayed" or "if I had stayed"?

Tags: conditional-constructions

Could you explain to me which structure was used in this sentence in the following passage.

> I developed into a very different person than I would have done **had I stayed** in Australia...

Should it be written also like :

> I developed into a very different person than I would have done **if I had stayed** in Australia...

[image]

Answer (score 4):

"If I had" and "had I" mean the same thing and are completely interchangeable.  The only difference is "had I" is more formal. They are both past perfect conditional.

Comment: Also, I found some links that aren't entirely about the use of "had I" vs. "if I had" but they are still about past perfect conditional, and you might find them useful. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64294/past-perfect-would-have-ed-participle-past-simple-would-infinitive http://www.engvid.com/english-grammar-inversion/ http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/verbs/if-i-would-have-vs-if-i-had/