# What's the exact meaning of "Did one but know" in "Sonnet" by Christina Rossetti?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions, pronouns, negation, do-support

What's the exact meaning of "Did one but know" at the end of "Sonnet" by Christina Rossetti?

This is the full context：

---

**Sonnet**

by Christina Rosetti

> I wish I could remember that first day,
>   First hour, first moment of your meeting me,
>   If bright or dim the season, it might be
>   Summer or winter for aught I can say;
>   So unrecorded did it slip away,
>   So blind was I to see and to foresee,
>   So dull to mark the budding of my tree
>   That would not blossom yet for many a May.
>
> If only I could recollect it, such
>   A day of days! I let it come and go
>   As traceless as a thaw of bygone snow;
>   It seemed to mean so little, meant so much;
>   If only now I could recall that touch,
>   First touch of hand in hand – Did one but know!

---

And can anyone explain the meaning of 'but' here?

Comment: I think *Did one **but** know!* = *If **only** I knew!*

Comment: @snailboat: I'm not going to pore over it too much (it's poetry, so quite possibly multiple interpretations are credible), but my first impression is that final exclamation/lament means something more like ***Had** I but known [realized **at the time**]* - i.e. that I was experiencing my first physical contact with you, which I now can't recall because I wasn't paying much attention (because I didn't know *then* how important it would seem to me *now*). Effectively, *If only I **had** known!*.

Comment: Sure, I don't think the perfect is required there, but it seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"But" here means "only"

See, [among others](http://www.onelook.com/?w=but&ls=a), definition 5 in [Old Websters](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=but&use1913=on) or modern [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/but), definition 10

> Did one but know!

means

> Did one only know!

Which is present tense, and equals

> If one only knew!

This is similar to

> Had I but known

which is past tense and [which means](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52686/had-i-stayed-or-if-i-had-stayed)

> If I had only known.

Other uses for your construction include:

1 [Did I But Know The Way](http://www.poemhunter.com/best-poems/ki-no-tsurayuki/did-i-but-know-the-way/)

> Did I but know the way  (If only I knew the way)
> I would go and pluck,
> On Suminoe's
> Shore the sprouting
> Grass to forget my love.

2 [Did But She Know](https://books.google.com/books?id=X8IiAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=%22Did%20she%20but%20know%22&source=bl&ots=tj8IZnb_AA&sig=tmAUAW5RKQgGlx4pzzMs2Fu7gyU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8hZVVY3BO4vwoASfxoCoDw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22Did%20she%20but%20know%22&f=false)

> November skies of blue and gray
> Hang over low;
> A quiet, hazy, chili day,
> Earth white with snow.
>
> As is the day, my heart is chill,
> I wander slow.
> With restless pain I murmur still
> "Did she but know!"
> ...

I murmur still: "If she only knew"

[3](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/490078-shepherds-did-they-but-know-it-walk-through-greater-halls)

> “Shepherds, did they but know it, walk through greater halls than kings.”

Shepherds, if they only knew it, walk...

[4](https://books.google.com/books?id=Maw7AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA287&lpg=RA1-PA287&dq=%22Did%20I%20but%20know%22&source=bl&ots=7ufc1IDgAO&sig=kVjIkGEc33Rx83g1KUKG9U-nGFs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ixJVVavPD4e0ogSonoH4Aw&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22Did%20I%20but%20know%22&f=false)

> "We cannot say, with this poor heathen, 'Ah, did I but know him, how would I love him and honor him.' for... we do know him."

"Ah, if only I knew him"

[5](https://books.google.com/books?id=rY1BAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=%22Did%20I%20but%20know%22&source=bl&ots=MygFyPnkje&sig=jTRuaYTE7l9QdbVoPNrQyIrZCnY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xxRVVdS5KYPwoATdkoCoBQ&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22Did%20I%20but%20know%22&f=false)

> "I, who would undergo all the plagues and miseries which any demon ever invented mankind to procure her any good; nay torture itself could not be misery to me, did I but know that she was happy!"

"If only I knew that she was happy."

*Etc, etc, etc.*